# Evernote Resource URLs

Tags: google-app-engine, evernote

I'm writing an application that takes a user's Evernote notes and displays them in a website inline.  By its very nature, people accessing the resources attached to a note will not be logged in. I'm looking at the bottom of [this page](http://dev.evernote.com/start/core/resources.php) and saw how to pass authentication credentials via POST and get the resource.  This is exactly what I need.

My question is how does this work in the real world?  If I pass authentication tokens to the Javascript client (not secure in the first place), I can't get the resource because of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` restrictions.  The only other way I can think of doing this is saving all of the resources to my server and serving them from there, but that's not ideal (Google App Engine).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, Evernote does not support CORS yet. You can do it in a chrome extension or get it on the server side.